# SD Card Ignores Formating and file writes

Tags: sd-card

I have a 16 GB Micro SD card from Samsung, and have only had it for about 4 months. I have not used it recently, but now that I have tried to format it, it does not work. On all the tools I have used (Disk util on mac, windows explorer, a lot of tools on linux, Apple Pi Baker, and the official SD card formatter, CCleaner), the format says that it has been completed sucsessfully, but if i take it out and reinsert it, it still has the same files on it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you've managed to trigger the firmware write protect by, for instance, removing the card without unmounting, or simply if it had a write error whilst copying a file, then you may as well just throw it away. It cannot be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the lock switch on micro SD adapter ?

[image]

Sounds crazy but perhaps a way to help ?